# Lossy decompositions

Tags: database, normalization, database-normalization

If a relation is decomposed into 2 sub relations such that the decomposition is lossy then can these sub-relations be in any normal form (3nf or bcnf)  if the parent relation is in bcnf ?

Consider a relation R(S,T,U,V) with following functional dependencies:-
S->T , T->U, U->V, V->S.

Now if I decompose the above relation into 2 relations R1 and R2 such that R1 intersection R2 is null like R1(S,T) and R2(U,V) , then is the decomposition in bcnf?

I know that R1 can have functional dependencies S->T, T->S and R2 can have functional dependencies U->V and V->U which makes it look like BCNF.

My question was do we consider the decomposition as BCNF even though it's not a valid decomposition ? By not valid I mean lossy decomposition.

Comment: This isn't clear, like most informal phrasings that involve "a", "can", "any", etc. Eg there is *a certain* relation that is in BCNF that has *a certain* lossy binary decomposition that is in *some* NF. But then is the answer to your question true, or false? You need to phrase your statement using "for all relations R, [...]" & "for some relation S, [...]" (or its equivalent,"there exists a relation T where [...]"). Not just "a", "can", "any", "all", "some" etc. (There *might* be some unambiguous informal phrasing(s) using the latter. This isn't one.) PS To disprove, seek counter-examples.

Comment: There is no ambiguity in my question . I just asked if there is a possibility that the decomposed relations be in bcnf if the parent relation is in bcnf or in other words the possibility of a sub relation being in bcnf after lossy decomposition.

Comment: I suggest that you try to write your question & comment statements formally, because you will see that it's not clear what clear, formal statements express each of them. Also, unclear as they are, there's no way your question could, like your comment, be interpreted as asking whether the components could be in BCNF.

Comment: Your edit kept your unclear original question & added a completely different final question. Please figure out what your question is and ask only it, clearly. (There are now 2 phrasings in your question & 2 in your comment.) Re saying that a decomposition is in a certain NF, see my edited answer.

Comment: PS If the given FDs form a cover then the CKs are {{s},{t},{u},{v}} & R is in BCNF. When you sloppily say "R1 intersection R2 is null" I guess you mean that the intersection of the attribute sets of R1 & R2 is the null/empty set. R2's V->S should be V->U. When you strangely say that the components "can have" those FDs I guess you mean they *do* have them, ie they satisfy them. The components are in BCNF. The decomposition is lossy. Then you sloppy/unclearly say "valid" then define it, when you could have just said something that means something using proper technical terms in the first place.

Comment: In the PS I should have said, If the only constraints on R are those that follow from those FDs holding then the decomposition is lossy. Because the decomposition can be lossless while those FDs hold. That is when the original *also* is always the join of R1 & R2, ie when the JD {{s,t},{u,v}} holds in R.

Answer (score 0):

From your (unclear) question:

> If a relation is decomposed into 2 sub relations such that the decomposition is lossy

From a comment:

> I just asked if there is a possibility that the decomposed relations be in bcnf if the parent relation is in bcnf

If that's your question then the answer is yes, there is.

Consider a variable with CK (candidate key) {a} in BCNF that can hold this:

```
a b
1 2
3 4
```

Binary decomposition {{a},{b}} is lossy with components in BCNF.

(When trying to prove something wrong always check out some simple cases in case you can find a counterexample as proof.)

> do we consider the decomposition as BCNF even though it's not a valid decomposition ? By not valid I mean lossy decomposition.

When we say that a decomposition is in a certain NF, that's short for saying that all its components are in that NF. But we only ever use this shorthand when the decomposition is lossless, ie when "decomposition" is understood to be short for "lossless decomposition", because lossy decompositions are not useful.